Problemas con publicación en asp net core
Tengo una Solución ASP NET CORE NET6 don 2 aplicaciones , un api y una solución web. Corre sin problemas pero a la hora de publicar después de logearme en la aplicación me salE este problema:
Error.
An error occurred while processing your request.
Request ID: 00-b281ac59057d7f9e0088372902e36033-eae5d19cb4a503d7-00
Development Mode
Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred.
The Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed applications. It can result in displaying sensitive information from exceptions to end users. For local debugging, enable the Development environment by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development and restarting the app.
No tengo idea de porqué sale esto.

Entiendes lo que te dice el mensaje?

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!
